# The Fourier Transform of a periodic function

Tags: fourier-transform, periodic-functions

I am  confused about this thing

The definition of the Fourier transform of a function $f \in \mathbb{L}^1( \mathbb{R})$ (integrable function ):
$$F(f)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2\pi xt}dt$$
but if I want to compute the fourier transform of a periodic function ($f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example ) 
what i have to do 
1) consider

$f(x)=\sin(x)$ for $x \in [0,2\pi]$

$ f(x)=0 $  else

2) compute the fourier trannformation of $\sin(x)$ as a function definied on   $ 
 \;\mathbb{R}   (f(x)=\sin(x) $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R})$

Comment: The Fourier transform does not exist as  an ordinary function. The integral does not converge.

Comment: Let $\hat{f}_n(x) = \int_{-n}^n f(x)e^{-2i \pi xt}dt$ when $f$ is $L^1_{loc}$ and $T$-periodic then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\hat{f}_n$ converges only in the sense of distributions, to $\hat{f}(x)=\sum_k c_k(f) \delta(x-k/T)$ where $c_k(f) = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f(t)e^{-2i \pi kt/T}dt$ is the Fourier series coefficient. The inverse Fourier transform is just the Fourier series, which converges in the sense of distributions.